# How to add a successful prompt

Tags: php, vmware, clarity, vmware-clarity

I'm trying to add a prompt after registration using this framework

I would like something like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/iwthtu5.png]

But with like 'Registration Success' or something?

My code: https://gist.github.com/crowns/e116eedaddc54b3b8e1f6f68f86917d1

Framework I'm using: http://vmware.github.io/clarity/

If someone could help me with this that'd be great!

Comment: You should include any code in the question itself.

Comment: It was too much to add, it didn't look formatted correctly, pardon me.

Comment: @Crowns, if your code is too long to paste into your question, that is a sign that you need to make an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that. no one here wants to read through 150 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static prompt using HTML and CSS and show it only if the form is submitted successfully using PHP.

Comment: how would I go about doing that

Comment: Modify your code in line no 67 to $result  = mysql_query("update users set md5_id='$md5_id' where id='$user_id'"); Then check if($result->num_rows) {your prompt here in variable}. Then at the bottom or wherever you want add a PHP conditional which will check if the prompt variable exists or not. If it does then it displays

Comment: I still don't understand?